# Change Default Binding/Textbox StringFormat in xaml

Tags: wpf, xaml, data-binding

I am creating a form with a lot of textboxes that have text attributes as declared below:

```
Text="{Binding Path=SomeField, StringFormat='\{0:#,##0.##\}', Mode=TwoWay, ValidatesOnExceptions=true, NotifyOnValidationError=true, Source={StaticResource statementsMainsViewSource}}"
```

In order to save bulk space & keystrokes, I want to know if there is a way to setup default textboxes in each window using styles (eg somewhat similar to the incorrect code below):

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
        <Setter Property="StringFormat" Value="\{0:#,##0.##\}" />
</Style>
```

Unfortunately, it's the binding stuff that has the property, not the text box, and i don't know how to set a binding style.

Can anyone point me to the correct syntax for changing default binding StringFormats - or can anyone suggest how I can do what I'm trying?

cheers and tia

mcalex

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
public class TextBinding:Binding
{
    public TextBinding()
    {
        Mode = BindingMode.TwoWay;
        StringFormat = @"\{0:#,##0.##\}";
        ValidatesOnExceptions = true;
        NotifyOnValidationError = true;
    }
}

   xmlns:myBinding="clr-namespace:WpfApplication2">
<Grid>
    <TextBox Text="{myBinding:TextBinding Path=SomeProperty}"/>
</Grid>
```

Now you can Bind this way to all Textboxes without setting the above 4 properties of binding they will be automatically applied. I hope this will help you to get an idea.

Comment: This nearly does the job. But when I drag/drop the field from DataSources into the textbox in the designer, it overwrites the `"{myBinding:TextBinding ..."` and replaces it with standard binding syntax.  That's why i was hoping for a default/template type solution

PS: tried to upvote, but i don't gots the reputation yet